# $\dim V=2$ , $T,S \in \mathscr L(V)$ $\implies$ $(TS-ST)^2:=(TS-ST)\circ (TS-ST)$ commutes with every element of $\mathscr L(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a two dimensional vector space and $T,S$ be two linear transforms on $V$ , then is it true that $(TS-ST)^2:=(TS-ST)\circ (TS-ST)$ commutes with every linear transform on $V$ ?

Comment: your thoughts??

Comment: I see your questions very regularly on MSE, and you never make any attempts to solve them. Why?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is YES. Indeed, the matrix $U=ST-TS$ has zero trace, so it is of
the form

$$
U=\begin{pmatrix} x&y \\ z & -x\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then one can compute that

$$
U^2=\begin{pmatrix} x&y \\ z & -x\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x&y \\ z & -x\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} x^2+yz & 0 \\ 0 & x^2+yz\end{pmatrix}=(x^2+yz)I_2,
$$

so $U^2$ commutes with every other $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Is there a generalization of this for higher dimensions?

Comment: @posilon No, because in general the set of all commutants $ST-TS$ coincides wit the set of zero trace matrices, and any (complex) matrix can be written as the square of a zero trace (complex) matrix when $n\geq 3$ (nice exercise).